# JPA @OneToMany collection is null

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have these two entities 
**Permit**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERMITS")
public class Permit extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="USR_ID")
    private User user;
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("role ASC")
    private List<Permit> permits;

    public List<Permit> getPermits() {
        return permits;
    }

    public void setPermits(List<Permit> permits) {
        this.permits = permits;
    }

    // getters, setters etc ...
```

When i load them with

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.permits")
```

Or with any other method permits attribute is always null. I would understand if it was some PersistentBag but it is null and when i assign new ArrayList to it, it is not overridden so it seems that hibernate does nothing with this attribute. 
From other side (from Permit) it works fine. When i do

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Permit p")
```

I see all permits with fetched users.
Whats wrong with my mapping?

Comment: Without `JOIN FETCH u.permits` you should be able to request `permits` from the `User`: `SELECT u FROM User u`

Comment: I am not. Permits are null if i query User with or without the fetch.

Comment: can you please try, after removing `@OrderBy("role ASC")`
    `

Comment: Removing @OrderBy had no effect.

Comment: you defined getters and setters properly ?

Comment: Added getter and setter in the post

Comment: In your database, does the user rows you are querying definitely have a non-null relationship to a set of permits?